# How to use a regex to match a symbol like a string literal in a hash object?

Tags: ruby, regex, hash

Using `str` as the key in the hash works fine.

```
string = 'The dog and cat'
replace = {'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow'}
replace.default = 'unknown'

string.gsub(/\w+/, replace)
 # => "unknown woof unknown meow"
```

**How do I get the same result with a `sym` as the hash key?**

```
string = 'The dog and cat'
replace = {dog: 'woof', cat: 'meow'}
replace.default = 'unknown'

string.gsub(/\w+/, replace)
 # => "unknown unknown unknown unknown" (actual result)
 # => "unknown woof unknown meow" using symbols as hash keys? (desired result)
```

*Some attempts I made:*

```
string.gsub(/(\w+)/, replace[:$1])
 # => "unknown unknown unknown unknown"

string.split.map(&:to_sym).to_s.gsub(/\w+/, replace)
 # => "[:unknown, :unknown, :unknown, :unknown]"
```

Comment: You can't use a regex with a symbol. They are incompatible beasts. Instead, use `to_s` to convert the symbol to a string, then the regex match will work. Using `to_s` on a String returns the string, so it won't matter. Using `to_s` on most simple objects will return a String that can be searched also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the below code :

```
string = 'The dog and cat'
replace = {dog: 'woof', cat: 'meow'}
replace.default = 'unknown'
string.gsub(/\w+/, replace)
```

You made the hash `replace`, default value as `'unknown'`. It means, when you will look for a value from the hash `replace`, if the key is not present, then the hash would return you `unknown` as value. It will work this way as you defined the hash in this way.

Now `#gsub` method, giving all the word match like `'the'`, `'dog'` etc, but none of those string are key to your hash `replace`, thus as I said above, hash `replace` will return the default value every time `unknown`.

Remember - In the hash `replace = {dog: 'woof', cat: 'meow'}`, keys are symbols, like `:dog`, `:cat`. But `#gsub` gives you all the match as a *string*.

Thus to make it work you need to use block as below :

```
string = 'The dog and cat'
replace = {dog: 'woof', cat: 'meow'}
replace.default = 'unknown'
string.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| replace[m.to_sym] } 
# => "unknown woof unknown meow"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep all the other words as-is, but just replace what's in the hash, you can do this:

```
replace = {'dog' => 'woof', 'cat' => 'meow'}
my_string = 'The dog and cat'
my_string.gsub(/\w+/) {|m| (replace.key? m) ? replace[m] : m}
```

Which will yield:

```
The woof and meow
```

Or more compactly (thanks to @Arup for the hint):

```
my_string.gsub(/\w+/) {|m| replace.fetch(m, m)}
```

Comment: If so I would write `my_string.gsub(/\w+/) { |m| replace.fetch(m.to_sym, m) }` ... :)

Comment: @Arup good catch, in this example, more precisely, `replace.fetch(m, m)` since I'm using strings.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you'd want to replace "unknown" words with `unknown`; That's not something very useful in normal string processing or template-processing code. As a result it seems like you're asking an X-Y question, wanting to know how to do "Y" when you should really be doing "X".

Here's some code, and information that could be helpful:

```
string = 'The dog and cat'
replacement_hash = {dog: 'woof', cat: 'meow'}
```

First, be very careful using a variable with the same name as a method. Ruby can figure out what you mean usually, but your brain will fail to always make the connection. The brains of people who use, or maintain, your code might not do as well. So, instead of a hash called `replace`, use something like `replacement_hash`.

Normally we don't want to define a hash using symbols as the keys if we're going to be doing search and replace actions against a string. Instead we'd want the actual string values; It's more straight-forward that way. That said, this will walk through a hash with symbols as keys, and generate a new hash using the equivalent strings as keys:

```
replacement_hash2 = Hash[replacement_hash.keys.map(&:to_s).zip(replacement_hash.values)] # => {"dog"=>"woof", "cat"=>"meow"}
```

We [give `gsub` a regular expression](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-gsub), and it will walk through the string looking for matches to that pattern. One of its cool features is that we can give it a hash, and for each match found it will look through the associated hash and return the value for matching keys.

Here's how to easily build a pattern that matches the keys in the hash. I'm using a case-insensitive pattern, but YMMV:

```
key_regex = /\b(?:#{ Regexp.union(replacement_hash.keys.map(&:to_s)).source })\b/i # => /\b(?:dog|cat)\b/i
```

In its most basic form, here's a `gsub` that uses a pattern to look up values in a hash:

```
string.gsub(key_regex, replacement_hash2) # => "The woof and meow"
```

It's also possible to search the string using a pattern, then pass the "hits" to a block, which then computes the needed replacements:

```
string.gsub(key_regex) { |w| replacement_hash2[w] } # => "The woof and meow"
```

or:

```
string.gsub(key_regex) { |w| replacement_hash[w.to_sym] } # => "The woof and meow"
```

*But wait! There's more!*

If you don't want the surgical approach, you can also use a more generic ("shotgun approach") regex pattern and handle both hits and misses when looking in the hash:

```
string.gsub(/\S+/) { |w| replacement_hash[w.to_sym] || 'unknown' } # => "unknown woof unknown meow"
```

That turns your original code into a single, simple, line of code. Change the regexp as necessary.

Meditate on this is the contents of the block above don't make sense:

```
replacement_hash[:dog] # => "woof"
replacement_hash[:foo] # => nil
nil || 'unknown' # => "unknown"
```

Notice, that it's important to convert the suspect/target word matched into a symbol using your `replacement_hash` hash. That can get sticky, or convoluted, because some strings don't convert to symbols cleanly and result in a double-quoted symbol. You'd have to account for that in your hash definition:

```
'foo'.to_sym # => :foo
'foo_bar'.to_sym # => :foo_bar
'foo-bar'.to_sym # => :"foo-bar"
'foo bar'.to_sym # => :"foo bar"
```